# What is a “transition table" in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, table, postgresql-10

The page describing [what's new in Postgres 10](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Transition_Tables_for_Triggers) mentions “Transition Tables for Triggers”.

> **Transition Tables for Triggers**
>
> This feature makes `AFTER STATEMENT` triggers both useful and performant by exposing, as appropriate, the old and new rows to queries. Before this feature, `AFTER STATEMENT` triggers had no direct access to these, and the workarounds were byzantine and had poor performance. Much trigger logic can now be written as `AFTER STATEMENT`, avoiding the need to do the expensive context switches at each row that FOR EACH ROW triggers require.

What is a transition table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You know how there are `OLD` and `NEW` record-variables for `FOR EACH ROW` triggers?

Transition tables are the `FOR EACH STATEMENT` equivalents. They're tables with the old and new tuples, so your triggers can see what changed.

Answer (score 13):

I really like Craig's explanation of the feature. The SQL-2011 Spec defines them in the context of a trigger as *"a collection of rows being deleted, inserted or replaced is known as a transition table."* A [similar explanation is provided in the docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

> While transition tables for `AFTER` triggers are specified using the `REFERENCING` clause in the standard way, the row variables used in `FOR EACH ROW` triggers may not be specified in `REFERENCING` clause. They are available in a manner which is dependent on the language in which the trigger function is written. Some languages effectively behave as though there is a `REFERENCING` clause containing `OLD ROW AS OLD NEW ROW AS NEW.`

Essentially they make the whole statement's changes available to you, which is super handy. For reference, the DDL on create trigger looks like this with transitions tables

```
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS oldtable NEW TABLE AS newtable
```

You can see an [example here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtrigger.html), and here is one from the [test suite](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/a571c7f661a7b601aafcb12196d004cdb8b8cb23/src/test/regress/sql/plpgsql.sql),

```
CREATE TABLE transition_table_base (id int PRIMARY KEY, val text);

CREATE FUNCTION transition_table_base_ins_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  t text;
  l text;
BEGIN
  t = '';
  FOR l IN EXECUTE
           $q$
             EXPLAIN (TIMING off, COSTS off, VERBOSE on)
             SELECT * FROM newtable
           $q$ LOOP
    t = t || l || E'\n';
  END LOOP;

  RAISE INFO '%', t;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER transition_table_base_ins_trig
  AFTER INSERT ON transition_table_base
  REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS oldtable NEW TABLE AS newtable
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE transition_table_base_ins_func();
```

Some additional notes

1. They're only available on `AFTER` triggers.
2. They take into account things like `ON CONFLICT`.

<strike>It's important to point out that **it's not entirely sure to be available in PG 10**. There are lots of [open issues with transition tables](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_10_Open_Items#Transition_Tables). Most have patches. There is some infighting which is kind of routine. It seems the heavy lifting was picked up by someone else. The [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87h8z1ov57.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk) indicates that we'll know soon.</strike>

[Author responded - seems to be going well again,.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87d19oou0q.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk)

Comment: The example you cite is supposedly from the postres code? It is not valid... It is referencing OLD TABLE on an AFTER INSERT trigger... docs say ["OLD TABLE may only be specified once, and only for a trigger that can fire on UPDATE or DELETE"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html#id-1.9.3.93.6)