# Unique sets of IDs from table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, unique-constraint

I want to represent mixture of arbitrary numbers of chemicals. Since the relationship between chemicals and mixtures here is many-to-many, I thought I'd implement it like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE chemicals (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    chem_id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE mixtures (
    mixture_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
);
CREATE TABLE mixture_chems (
    mixture_id INTEGER REFERENCES mixtures (mixture_id),
    chem_id INTEGER REFERENCES chemicals (chem_id)
);
```

But I also would like to enforce that there is only one (unique) `mixture_id` that is referred to by any particular combination of `chem_id` (via the rows in the `mixture_chems` table).

How could I implement this in PostgreSQL?

One person suggested I might need to use triggers to compute some new value, that uniquely identifies a mixture, and then enforce uniqueness on that. Thoughts on how to implement that, or whether it'd be appropriate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with *that person*. Here is an implementation.

Basically, add a `UNIQUE` array column of all `chem_id`s to table `mixtures` and keep it current with triggers. Arrays must be sorted consistently, I use the additional module **[intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html)** for that and to optimize performance.

For lack of definition I assume frequent multi-row writes, making it a perfect candidate for **transition tables** introduced with Postgres 10. See:

- [What is a “transition table" in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177463/what-is-a-transition-table-in-postgres)

**Important note:** Technically, this works in Postgres 10. But while testing I ran into a bug of intarray functions that seemed oddly familiar: empty arrays would not compare equal due to incorrect internal array dimensions. [Tom Lane found and fixed this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/01783ac36de1aac9bf8d19f6c2814778188d4523#diff-ab1478ac7662b06703431cad1c502ccc) for Postgres 11, but it was not backported to Postgres 10. I strongly advise to use **Postgres 11** with this.

<sub>Turns out to be another instance of a bug I reported myself earlier. See [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/716ea626a88ac510523ab3af5bc779d78eeced58) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20170923125723.1448.39412%40wrigleys.postgresql.org). Took me a while to reproduce and get the full picture.</sub>

This uses a variety of advanced features. Not recommended for beginners.

#### Code

```
CREATE TABLE chemicals (
  chem_id serial UNIQUE NOT NULL
, name text PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE mixtures (
  mixture_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, chem_ids int[] UNIQUE  -- default NULL !
);

CREATE TABLE mixture_chems (
  mixture_id int REFERENCES mixtures (mixture_id)
, chem_id int    REFERENCES chemicals (chem_id)
);
```

`INSERT` trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_mixture_chems_insaft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE mixtures AS m
   SET    chem_ids = sort(COALESCE(m.chem_ids, '{}') + n.chem_ids)
   FROM  (
      SELECT mixture_id, array_agg(chem_id) AS chem_ids
      FROM   new_table
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) n
   WHERE m.mixture_id = n.mixture_id;

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER mixture_chems_insaft
AFTER INSERT ON mixture_chems
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_mixture_chems_insaft();
```

`UPDATE` trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_mixture_chems_upaft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE mixtures AS m
   SET    chem_ids = sort(COALESCE(m.chem_ids, '{}')
                        - COALESCE(o.chem_ids, '{}')
                        + COALESCE(n.chem_ids, '{}'))
   FROM  (
      SELECT mixture_id, array_agg(chem_id) AS chem_ids
      FROM   new_table
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) n
   FULL  JOIN (
      SELECT mixture_id, array_agg(chem_id) AS chem_ids
      FROM   old_table
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) o USING (mixture_id)
   WHERE m.mixture_id = COALESCE(n.mixture_id, o.mixture_id)
   AND   m.chem_ids IS DISTINCT FROM sort(COALESCE(m.chem_ids, '{}')
                                        - COALESCE(o.chem_ids, '{}')
                                        + COALESCE(n.chem_ids, '{}'));

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER mixture_chems_upaft
AFTER UPDATE ON mixture_chems
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
            OLD TABLE AS old_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_mixture_chems_upaft();
```

`DELETE` trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_mixture_chems_delaft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE mixtures AS m
   SET    chem_ids = m.chem_ids - o.chem_ids  -- assuming this does not upset sort order!
   FROM  (
      SELECT mixture_id, array_agg(chem_id) AS chem_ids
      FROM   old_table
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) o
   WHERE m.mixture_id = o.mixture_id
   AND   m.chem_ids IS DISTINCT FROM (m.chem_ids - o.chem_ids);

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER mixture_chems_delaft
AFTER DELETE ON mixture_chems
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_mixture_chems_delaft();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7cafba6e3dba9b92cacdc31add30a3bf)*

This implementation is *strict*: a mixture with no chemicals (`chem_ids = '{}'`) is just another case that is only allowed *once*. You may want to allow that multiple times instead. This state is only reached after deleting all existing components, newly inserted row in `mixtures` start out with `chem_ids IS NULL` to dodge this `UNIQUE` constraint.

And you may want to add a [`PRIMARY KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) to disallow adding the same chemical to a mixture multiple times:

```
CREATE TABLE mixture_chems (
  mixture_id INTEGER REFERENCES mixtures (mixture_id)
, chem_id INTEGER REFERENCES chemicals (chem_id)
, PRIMARY KEY (mixture_id, chem_id)
);
```

But my implementation works either way.

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)